# Function chatDidReceiveMessage not working Quickblox

Tags: android, ios, quickblox

I use this framework to create a messenger on Android and iOS.

In android I create a message and send it.
The server quickblox it comes !
I also see this message in the log of xcode... but no further response should not be, because the function - (void)chatDidReceiveMessage:(QBChatMessage *)message is break point.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Code for sending message(Android)

    // create a message
QBChatMessage chatMessage = new QBChatMessage();
chatMessage.setProperty("save_to_history", "1"); // Save a message to history
chatMessage.setBody("Hi there");
chatMessage.setDateSent(new Date().getTime()/1000);

// attach a audio
QBAttachment attachment = new QBAttachment("audio");
attachment.setId(file.getId().toString());
chatMessage.addAttachment(attachment);

try {
     currentChatRoom.sendMessage(chatMessage);
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Code in log XCode

```
2015-12-13 16:05:27.638 Messenger[462:5623] [ChatService] Message RCV: <message xmlns="jabber:client" id="566d5efb1fecfa062778dcd9" to="6804658-31081@chat.quickblox.com/A9320123-BD0A-4C80-BD81-F729D036877A" type="groupchat" from="31081_56616b87a0eb4756f2000b6d@muc.chat.quickblox.com/6919398"><body>Hi there</body><extraParams xmlns="jabber:client"><attachment type="audio" id="3173128"/><date_sent>1450011927</date_sent><save_to_history>1</save_to_history><message_id>566d5efb1fecfa062778dcd9</message_id><dialog_id>56616b87a0eb4756f2000b6d</dialog_id></extraParams><delay xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" stamp="2015-12-13T13:05:27Z"/></message>
```

I don't understand((

Comment: Please show your iOS code how you use chatDidReceiveMessage: method

Comment: Hello(Здравствуйте) Igor.

My message contains an audio file. I want to get the link and download it

`
- (void)chatDidReceiveMessage:(QBChatMessage *)message{

NSLog(@"chatDidReceiveMessage");

    for(QBChatAttachment *attachment in message.attachments){
        // or if you have only file ID
        NSString *privateUrl = [QBCBlob privateUrlForID:[attachment.ID integerValue]];

//////
simple code


    }
}
`
Break point is on NSLog(@"chatDidReceiveMessage");
But in Log I don't see this message

Comment: In viewDidload():

`[[QBChat instance] addDelegate:self]`

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, you send messages to chat room (not private chat), and then you should use **chatRoomDidReceiveMessage:fromDialogID:** instead. I faced the same problem, described in [chatDidReceiveMessage: not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395261/chatdidreceivemessage-not-called) post.

Comment: Аccording to the documents , after sending the message in the usual chat (no private)- should invoke methods `chatDidReceiveMessage`

Comment: I checked on private chat - `chatDidReceiveMessage` works

Then check for a group chat function - `chatRoomDidReceiveMessage` - also works

Comment: Can you point where in docunents you found that chatDidReceiveMessage must be invoked for private chat? I was unable to found explicit mentions of it, while in sample they use chatRoomDidReceiveMessage.

Comment: These line in documentation:

`[[QBChat instance] addDelegate:self];
 
...
 
QBChatDialog *privateChatDialog = ...;
 
QBChatMessage *message = [QBChatMessage message];
[message setText:@"Hey there"];
//
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
params[@"save_to_history"] = @YES;
[message setCustomParameters:params];
//
[privateChatDialog sendMessage:message completionBlock:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
 
}];
 
 
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark QBChatDelegate
 
- (void)chatDidReceiveMessage:(QBChatMessage *)message{
 
}`

Comment: As I understood from their example , they use additional libraries (QMServices) and do not use these functions directly